# How to display different image depending on theme in hugo?

Tags: javascript, html, themes, hugo

I'm building a site in Hugo. I'm using the [hello friend ng](https://themes.gohugo.io/hugo-theme-hello-friend-ng/) theme. I want to add a svg image to the main site, but I want it to change depending on whether the selected theme is light or dark.

That theme toggle is handled by `theme.js`:

```js
const theme = window.localStorage && window.localStorage.getItem("theme");
const themeToggle = document.querySelector(".theme-toggle");
const isDark = theme === "dark";
var metaThemeColor = document.querySelector("meta[name=theme-color]");

if (theme !== null) {
  document.body.classList.toggle("dark-theme", isDark);
  isDark
    ? metaThemeColor.setAttribute("content", "#252627")
    : metaThemeColor.setAttribute("content", "#fafafa");
}

themeToggle.addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.body.classList.toggle("dark-theme");
  window.localStorage &&
    window.localStorage.setItem(
      "theme",
      document.body.classList.contains("dark-theme") ? "dark" : "light"
    );
  document.body.classList.contains("dark-theme")
    ? metaThemeColor.setAttribute("content", "#252627")
    : metaThemeColor.setAttribute("content", "#fafafa");
});
```

But i don't know how to access the variable it's using.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't manage to do exactly that, but I found a workaround which satisfies my needs, so I'm posting it in case someone finds it valuable.

Rather than using `<img>` with links to different svg images, I decided to use `<svg>` and copy the content of my image there, since it's just xml. Then, I removed properties such as `stroke` and `fill`, wrapped that `<svg>` in a `<div` with a custom class that I then control by css.

I'm not sure if that's the best approach but it seems to work for me.